# How to draw a thin line regularly across a cylinder

Tags: modeling

I have a vase at home that I found challenging for the newby I am in blender. I understand the title of my question is probably not very clear so I found best to share a picture of the vase. The part of the vase I haven't found any solution to draw is the thin vertical line. I tried using bevel but this makes something too regular between the "hole" and the plane surface. In addition, the thickness of the vase has to decrease around the top as the diameter decrease. For this, the best I found is to draw the line with the cylinder completely straight and then to scale the top of the vase by applying first a series of edge loops.

Any idea or suggestion would be most appreciated.

Steph.[image: Vase]

Answer (score 1):

The *Simple Deform* modifier is what you need!

- Create your profile, extrude it, don't keep the faces on the sides.

[image]

- Give it an *Array* modifier, enable *Merge* and *First Last* options.

[image]

- Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier, choose *Bend* mode and an *Angle* of 360°.

[image]

- Continue to build your section the way you want it to be, it will be replicated all around.

[image]

- Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, add edge loops to sharpen the edges, etc...

[image]

Comment: Thank you moonboots! I've started to test your suggestion and it starts to look like the original vase. I'll post a picture once finished.

Comment: Hi Moonboots, took me some time but managed to do it. Before applying the array and simple deform modifiers, I created the form using a Beziers curve to have something very close to the original form of the vase. Transformed the curve to a mesh then applied the 2 modifiers with 128 items in the array. Very Happy with the result, I'll try to upload a rendered picture of the vase. Thanks again !